# Nearest match of using data.table roll = 'nearest'

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to find the nearest match on the column 'date' using the package data.table and the argument roll='nearest'. I first match on another column (letters):

```
set.seed(1)
A <- data.table( dates.A = seq.Date(as.Date('2008-01-01'),as.Date('2008-01-31'), by = '3 days'), 
                 letters.A = LETTERS[1:4] , value.A = runif(4) )

B <- data.table( date.B = seq.Date(as.Date('2008-01-01'),as.Date('2008-01-05'), by = 'days'), 
                 letters.B = LETTERS[1:4] , value.B = runif(4) )

#### Define the columns I merge on

A[, ':=' (dates.merge = dates.A, letters.merge = letters.A)]
B[, ':=' (dates.merge = date.B, letters.merge = letters.B)]
setkeyv(A, c('letters.merge','dates.merge'))
setkeyv(B, c('letters.merge','dates.merge'))

result <- B[A, roll = 'nearest']

#### As a side note, how do I avoid the change in order of my data.tables??
setorder(result,dates.A,letters.A)
setorder(A,dates.A)
setorder(B,date.B)
```

The output of result, A, and B looks as such:

```
> result
        date.B letters.B   value.B dates.merge letters.merge    dates.A letters.A   value.A
 1: 2008-01-01         A 0.2016819  2008-01-01             A 2008-01-01         A 0.2655087
 2: 2008-01-02         B 0.8983897  2008-01-04             B 2008-01-04         B 0.3721239
 3: 2008-01-03         C 0.9446753  2008-01-07             C 2008-01-07         C 0.5728534
 4: 2008-01-04         D 0.6607978  2008-01-10             D 2008-01-10         D 0.9082078
 5: 2008-01-05         A 0.2016819  2008-01-13             A 2008-01-13         A 0.2655087
 6: 2008-01-02         B 0.8983897  2008-01-16             B 2008-01-16         B 0.3721239
 7: 2008-01-03         C 0.9446753  2008-01-19             C 2008-01-19         C 0.5728534
 8: 2008-01-04         D 0.6607978  2008-01-22             D 2008-01-22         D 0.9082078
 9: 2008-01-05         A 0.2016819  2008-01-25             A 2008-01-25         A 0.2655087
10: 2008-01-02         B 0.8983897  2008-01-28             B 2008-01-28         B 0.3721239
11: 2008-01-03         C 0.9446753  2008-01-31             C 2008-01-31         C 0.5728534
> A
       dates.A letters.A   value.A dates.merge letters.merge
 1: 2008-01-01         A 0.2655087  2008-01-01             A
 2: 2008-01-04         B 0.3721239  2008-01-04             B
 3: 2008-01-07         C 0.5728534  2008-01-07             C
 4: 2008-01-10         D 0.9082078  2008-01-10             D
 5: 2008-01-13         A 0.2655087  2008-01-13             A
 6: 2008-01-16         B 0.3721239  2008-01-16             B
 7: 2008-01-19         C 0.5728534  2008-01-19             C
 8: 2008-01-22         D 0.9082078  2008-01-22             D
 9: 2008-01-25         A 0.2655087  2008-01-25             A
10: 2008-01-28         B 0.3721239  2008-01-28             B
11: 2008-01-31         C 0.5728534  2008-01-31             C
> B
       date.B letters.B   value.B dates.merge letters.merge
1: 2008-01-01         A 0.2016819  2008-01-01             A
2: 2008-01-02         B 0.8983897  2008-01-02             B
3: 2008-01-03         C 0.9446753  2008-01-03             C
4: 2008-01-04         D 0.6607978  2008-01-04             D
5: 2008-01-05         A 0.2016819  2008-01-05             A
```

However, note that the nearest match on date for dates.A '2008-01-07' should be '2008-01-05' (see in B) instead of '2008-01-03'. The same is true for all the dates below '2008-01-07' in dates.A of result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you have `letters.merge` as one of your key as well so the result is as expected.

Comment: try printing these `B[.("A")]` and `A[.("A")]` and `B[.("A")][A[.("A")], roll="nearest"]`

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow what you mean

Comment: the columns that you want to merge on includes `letters.merge`. hence, the join is performed on this first before it is performed on `dates.merge` for the nearest.

Comment: I see, you are correct, I will delete this post

Comment: maybe post a solution, rather than delete?